# How to choose how many times to run single CMD command in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I have written a code in Visual Basic. It works, but i want to be able to choose how many times a DOS command will run.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim command As String
    command = "ping " + "-l " + TextBox2.Text + " /t " + TextBox1.Text
    Shell("cmd.exe /k" & command, 0)
End Sub
```

So i have a TextBox called "TextBox3" where i wanna be able to choose from 1-100, how many times the command will run.

Comment: Umm, why not use a loop?

Comment: And umm... Why are you running a DOS command from VB? There has to be a much better way of doing whatever you're trying to do. Perhaps a better question would be to ask about what you really want to accomplish, instead of relying on some archaic batch file method of doing things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can enter a number in `Textbox3` and command will run for that much time

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim command As String
    For i=0 To CInt(Me.Textbox3.Text)
        command = "ping " + "-l " + TextBox2.Text + " /t " + TextBox1.Text
        Shell("cmd.exe /k" & command, 0)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Textbox3 can also be a hidden object that is used to store the value in a global context.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable outside your sub :-

```
Dim cmdRunCount As Integer =0
```

then edit your sub to look like this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim command As String

    command = "ping " + "-l " + TextBox2.Text + " /t " + TextBox1.Text
    If cmdRunCount < 10 Then
        Shell("cmd.exe /k" & command, 0)
        cmdRuncount += 1
    End If
End Sub
```